# What exactly is the difference between the Xilinx warnings XST:1710 and XST:1895?

Tags: verilog, xilinx, synthesis

Can anyone please explain the difference between the two Xilinx warnings:

> Xst:1710 - FF/Latch reg_0 (without init value) has a constant value
>   of 0 in block . This FF/Latch will be trimmed during the
>   optimization process.
>
> Xst:1895 - Due to other FF/Latch trimming, FF/Latch reg_1 (without
>   init value) has a constant value of 0 in block . This FF/Latch
>   will be trimmed during the optimization process.

Assuming "reg" is a byte long register.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`reg_0` is optimized out (aka trimmed) because it is never assigned but is referenced during the assignment of other registers or nets. Since it does not has a specified init value the synthesizer is defaulting to zero. Therefore the synthesizer can save flop(s) and any use of `reg_0` in the design will be treated as logic 0.

`reg_1` is optimized out because its value is depended on other flops that were already optimized out. Using the example below: `reg_1` is depended on `reg_0`. Since `reg_0` will always be zero (because it is never assigned), `reg_1` will also always be zero. Hence why it says "Due to other FF/Latch trimming". The synthesizer saves flop(s) and any use of `reg_1` in the design will be treated as logic 0.

```
reg [7:0] reg_0;
reg [7:0] reg_1;
always @(posedge clk) begin
  reg_1 <= in & reg_0;
end
```

In summary:

- Xst:1710 - trimmed because never assigned
- Xst:1895 - trimmed because depended logic was trimmed

Same outcome but for different reasons.
If there is a bug in the design, resolving Xst:1710 issues it could automatically resolve the Xst:1895. If there isn't a bug, then these warnings point to dead code.